# Vertical line at a certain time display on Tradingview, pine script

Tags: line, pine-script

I want 2 lines to be displayed automatically at a certain time. This worked fine with the code below, but Monday is generally not displayed. I am in the timezone Utc+1, Berlin. What have I done wrong?

[image]

```
("Line", overlay=true)
t1 = time(period, "2100-2105")
t2 = time(period, "0030-0035")
Open = na(t1) ? na : green
Close = na(t2) ? na : green

bgcolor(Open, title="Open")
bgcolor(Close, title="Close")
```

Comment: you should tag the programming language you are using, this would increase the chances of getting a good answer.

Comment: Similar to what Duda said, try creating a small working JsFiddle so that people can see the actual problem.

Comment: Can you share the symbol and timeframe where the script miss the monday's signal? seems working fine on the charts i've tested.

Comment: In all currency pairs and in the time units from 1 minute to 30 minutes.

Comment: study("Line", overlay=true)
t1 = time(period, "2100-2101:12345")
t2 = time(period, "0030-0031:12345")
Open = na(t1) ? na : green
Close = na(t2) ? na : green                 
bgcolor(Open, title="Open")
bgcolor(Close, title="Close")                    The values :12345 stand here for the weekdays from Monday to Friday. That was the solution. Thanks for your help.